# Embeded video on html not playing

Tags: html

doing a school project and the video is not playing on the webpage
`An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: 9yPd2vpwAXOFFLlB) Learn More`

here is my code

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=oKilU3g0om0?"  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially it's the wrong link. Using the embed feature off of youtube, it looks like you want your iFrame to look like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oKilU3g0om0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you want to use your existing code, the only part you really need to change is the `src` link

Comment: THANKS MAN! LIFE SAVER! :D

Comment: Hi @semyj if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.